# Change WIX .exe installer Icon

Tags: wix, icons, installation

I have made a .exe installer for my application using Wix, but I'm unable to remove the following Icon for installer dialog.

[image]

I would be thankful if you assist me with this. 
Unfortunately I could not find any documentation clearly pointing to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must provide an alternate image. The the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` element set the LogoFile and/or LogoSideFile attributes to the paths of the images. You can use path relative to the bundle source file.

The documentation is [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/). The "Changing the WiX Standard Bootstrapper Application Branding" topic applies.

Comment: I have just discovered, and wanted to share, the side logo is only for url installers not rtf

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understand that you are not trying to change the Windows OS icon of installer file (.msi or .exe) but the images that appear in installer windows. Wix user interface have default icons with specific sizes for welcome & installation dialogs as well as banners [as follows](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html):

Variable name: Description  (Dimensions

- WixUIBannerBmp: Top banner (493 × 58)
- WixUIDialogBmp: Background bitmap used on the welcome and completion dialogs (493 × 312)
- WixUIExclamationIco: Exclamation icon on the WaitForCostingDlg   (32 × 32)
- WixUIInfoIco: Information icon on the cancel and error dialogs   (32 × 32)
- WixUINewIco: Button glyph on the BrowseDlg   (16 × 16)
- WixUIUpIco:  Button glyph on the BrowseDlg   (16 × 16)

You can find more info [here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/using-wix-ui-library/).
For Wix 3.0+, there are some explanations [here.](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry)

Comment: Slightly off topic but I landed here looking for an answer to changing the Icon of the bundle exe. So if you are trying to change the bundle exe icon then the IconSourceFile of the Bundle element can be used.